# Adding an incrementing number to each object in an array of objects with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, increment

Say I have an array of objects:

```js
const myArray = [{ color: 'red' }, { color: 'blue'}, { color: 'yellow'}]
```

How can I expand the object to add a key value pair to each element where the key is `number` and the value is a number that increments by one in each object? My desired outcome is:

```js
const myNewArray = [{ color: 'red', number: 1 }, { color: 'blue', number: 2 }, { color: 'yellow', number: 3 }]
```

Comment: This should be a trivial `for` loop. You can also use `.map()`. The number is the array index + 1.

Comment: Why not simply infer `number` from a given object's index in the array?

Answer (score 1):

```
const myNewArray = myArray.map((item, index) =>  { return {"number" :index, ...item} } )
```

Comment: maybe you should update your answer as: `const myNewArray = myArray.map((item, index) =>  { return {"number" :index + 1, ...item} } )`, as it requires 1..3, instead of 0..2. Overall, your answer solves the original request. @brendanreape88 should consider marking this as resolved.